# Cannot properly test files that are not part of the project directory in Angular + Karma

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-cli, karma-runner, istanbul

I have a following files structure:

- `projects`

  - `myproj` - Angular App
  - `myproj-lib` - Angular Library
- `shared` - shared code, used in both the app and the library

Both projects (App and Lib) were built using Angular CLI (angular.json is unchanged so far, apart from `codeCoverage` option). I'm not able to run the tests that are part of `shared` directory:

- for the app, tests are run properly, but coverage includes only project files (ones under `projects/myproj/src`)
- for the library tests, it always breaks on `Error: \TRUNCATED_PATH\shared\components\component-dir\component.ts` is missing from the TypeScript compilation

I think the problem for the App is that the coverage reporter does not see the `shared` directory, despite the fact that the tests (and even final report) include these (it only shows `src` from the project)

As for the library, I suppose it's something about how does the Karma resolve the paths so Typescript can see them.

My `test.ts` file (only additional paths were added):

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing-bundle';

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'; // tslint:disable-line
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

// Then we find all the tests.
const projectContext = require.context('./', true);
const sharedContext = require.context('../../../shared', true);

// And load the modules.
sharedContext.keys().map(sharedContext);
projectContext.keys().map(projectContext);
```

My `karma.conf.js`:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '../../shared',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['mocha'],
    mochaReporter: {
      ignoreSkipped: true
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    singleRun: false,
  });
};
```

My `tsconfig.spec.json` (I tried to modify paths, but it didn't help):

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../../",
    "rootDir": "../../",
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "inlineSources": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "preserveSymlinks": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "../../shared/**/*.ts",
    "../../shared/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": []
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem boiled down to including `shared` files two times in compilation. It's enough to have `projectContext.keys()` in `test.ts` as follows:

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing-bundle';

import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'; // tslint:disable-line
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

// Then we find all the tests.
const projectContext = require.context('./', true);

// And load the modules.
projectContext.keys().map(projectContext);
```

This works because `shared` is symlinked inside `lib` directory. Symlink, thanks to Git implementation, is even portable between Unix / Windows. That solved it!

So to sum up:

- Add symlink to `shared` directory inside projects instead of using real directory
- Remove duplicated `require.context`
- Use files from symlinked directory instead of going two paths outside of the project